# Rails Global Variable becomes nil across controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, global-variables

In my index action of my controller, I set `image = AppImage.new(:path => (Rails.root.to_s + "/highlands_girl.jpg"))`.  I then set `$image = image`.

I then have other controller actions where I call this global variable again, and sometimes it's nil and the image doesn't show up, but sometimes it does.  I can tell from debug prints in my log file that all of the calls to the global variable are after it's been set, so the `$image=image` happens before I call `image` again and find that it's nil.  In particular, I have a thumbnail action that the view calls five times.  On some loads, all five calls give an image, while in some, none do.

If it matters at all, this was not a problem when I was hosting on Heroku, but since I moved it to AWS it has this problem.  I'd like to avoid writing it to the database if possible, which is why I used new instead of create.

Comment: global variable? really?

Comment: Using app-level variables in Rails is a very dangerous practice, i see you've trapped the bug on the way. And it is good idea to refactor the code to avoid the app-level variables.

Comment: Haha I thought this might be a bad idea, guess it was.  Is there some alternative without saving it to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use global variables in rails (and, frankly, anywhere else) - there are much better places to store data. If your app image is a model, it is sufficient to store its id inside a session and write setter and getter in application controller:

```
#ApplicationController

def image=(image)
  session[:image_id] = (@image = image).try(:id)
end

def image
  @image ||= AppImage.find(session[:image_id]])
end
```

In case it is not  a model, it should be sufficient to story image path:

```
def image=(image)
  session[:image_path] = (@image = image).try(:path)
end

def image
  @image ||= AppImage.new(path: session[:image_path]])
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out and once I get it to work will accept it.

Comment: One question: this doesn't require that I add it to the database, right?

Comment: Well, the key question is - is your AppImage a model or not? If not, store image path in a session. Even if it is a session, id is non-nil only if model is saved, hence stored in a databse, so path-approach might be better. I'll update the answer

Comment: But you don't want to save it? - Go with second option.